# Navigation function is printing all its output twice

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

When I call the functions individually in main they work fine, just printing the desired message once. Calling both functions, causes navigation to print its messages twice.

I have looked up different solution. I tried using fflush(stdout) to no avail, i tried using a condition in the main to ensure they run individually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include "RAND_API.h"
#define MAXLEN 500

void lifeSupport();
void navigation();

int main()
{


    lifeSupport();
    navigation();
    return 0;
}

void lifeSupport()
{
        //Create pipe


        ret = write( myPipe[1], lifeSup1, strlen( lifeSup1 ) + 1 );
        //sleep( getRandExponential() * 10 );
        ret = write( myPipe2[1], lifeSup2, strlen( lifeSup2 ) + 1 );
        //sleep( getSRand() * 6 );
        sleep( getRandExponential() * 5 );
        ret = write( myPipe3[1], lifeSup3, strlen( lifeSup3 ) + 1 );
        sleep( getRandExponential() * 4 );
        ret = write( myPipe4[1], lifeSup4, strlen( lifeSup4 ) + 1 );
        close( myPipe[1] );
        close( myPipe2[1] );
        close( myPipe3[1] );
        close( myPipe4[1] );
    }
    else
    {
        //wait(NULL);
        close( myPipe[1] );
        close( myPipe2[1] );
        close( myPipe3[1] );
        close( myPipe4[1] );
        ret = read( myPipe[0], buffer, MAXLEN );
        printf( "%s", buffer );
        ret = read( myPipe2[0], buffer, MAXLEN );
        printf( "%s", buffer );
        ret = read( myPipe3[0], buffer, MAXLEN );
        printf( "%s", buffer );
        ret = read( myPipe4[0], buffer, MAXLEN );
        printf( "%s", buffer );
    }

}

void navigation()
{
       //create pipe

        ret = write( apipe[1], nav1, strlen( nav1 ) + 1 );
        ret = write( apipe2[1], nav2, strlen( nav2 ) + 1 );
        //sleep( getSRand() * 6 );
        ret = write( apipe3[1], nav3, strlen( nav3 ) + 1 );

        close( apipe[1] );
        close( apipe2[1] );
        close( apipe3[1] );

    }
    else
    {
        close( apipe[1] );
        close( apipe2[1] );
        close( apipe3[1] );

        ret = read( apipe[0], buff, MAXLEN );
        printf( "%s\n", buff );

        ret = read( apipe2[0], buff, MAXLEN );
        printf( "%s\n", buff );

        ret = read( apipe3[0], buff, MAXLEN );
        printf( "%s\n", buff );

        close( apipe[0] );
        close( apipe2[0] );
        close( apipe3[0] );

    }

}
```

output:

```
Life support system initiiated
Adjusting breathing gas levels
Adjusting enviroment
Life support system terminating
Initiating navigation system

Initiating navigation system
Making adjustments


Making adjustments
Adjustments done. Navigation system terminating.


Adjustments done. Navigation system terminating.
```

Expected output:

```
Life support system initiiated
Adjusting breathing gas levels
Adjusting enviroment
Life support system terminating
Initiating navigation system
Making adjustments

Adjustments done. Navigation system terminating.
```

Comment: Note that both the parent and the child will call the `navigation` function, which means that you have four processes after the `fork` in `navigation`.

Comment: @user3386109 what do you mean ? I am sorry if the answer is obvious, humor me I am still learning. I should not fork in navigation ?

Comment: Your edit seems to have removed much of the code you asked about. Now you just show parts of the program, and it can't be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `lifeSupport()`, it forks a child. The child writes messages to all the `myPipeX` pipes, the parent reads from them and prints the messages, then both the parent and child return to `main()`.

Then both processes call `navigation()`. They each create another child. The two children write to the `apipeX` pipes, the two parents read from them, and they each print the messages. So you get two copies of all the messages from `navigation()`.

In each function, the child should call `exit()` after it's done, rather than returning. Only the parent should return to `main()`.

Comment: Thanks that did it.